# I want slider text on overlap my image

Tags: image, text, slider, overlap

I am trying to **overlap my text on image**, but its not working on Google Chrome & Opera. And its working in Safari, Firefox & IE. 
 I uploaded both browsers screenshots, Waiting for your helpful answers. 
[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pISfV.jpg)

http://110.37.221.139/vanguard/vanguardmatrixnew/

Comment: Please show what you have tried (your code) so we can help editing that, not create you a new code. And your url is not accessible (page, not img).

Comment: Now please re-check the given URL it works.

Comment: you should add the code in the question! not all, but the one for that div (html and css)

Comment: A complete one slide item div is too long I mean too many characters in this that's its not possible to share with you. Did you check the URL?